# OpportunityLineItem does not have a lookup field to PricebookEntry. Am I missing something?

Tags: relationships, standard-objects, schema-builder

Apologies in advance if this is a stupid question.  Based on what I've seen in the documentation and various forum post answers, I believe the following relationships between Salesforce standard objects to be true:

- A PricebookEntry is a many-to-many table linking Product2 and Pricebook2
- An OpportunityLineItem is a many-to-many table linking an Opportunity and a PricebookEntry

However, in my org, I don't see a lookup field to the PricebookEntry.  The Opportunity Line Item is instead related to to Product2.

[image: Object relations in Schema Builder]

When I view the fields of the OpportunityLineItem object, I can only see the following standard fields:

- CreatedBy        = Lookup(User)
- Date             = Date
- Discount         = Percent(3, 2)
- Last Modified By = Lookup(User)
- Line Description = Text(255)
- List Price       = Currency(16, 2)
- Opportunity      = Lookup(Opportunity)
- Name             = Text(376)
- Product2         = Lookup(Product)
- ProductCode      = Text(255)
- Quantity         = Number(10,2)
- UnitPrice        = Currency(16,2)
- Subtotal         = Currency(16,2)
- TotalPrice       = Currency(16,2)

[image: Standard fields for OpportunityLineItem]

I'm really confused by the discrepancy between the Salesforce documentation and forum posts I've referenced vs what I can see in my own org.  Can anyone let me know what I'm missing?  Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** We are using the Enterprise edition of Salesforce.

Comment: what edition are you running?

Comment: @cropredy We are using Enterprise edition

Comment: Certainly seems like [it should](https://architect.salesforce.com/assets/images/data-models/sales-cloud-product-price-book-data-model.png).

Comment: Is there some reason the field might be hidden from me?  I'm a System Administrator, so I should have access to view everything, right?  (I did notice that System Administrators don't have "View all Data" and "Modify all Data" checked for Price books, but I also can't change these settings for the System Administrator profile.  The fact that they are unchecked also checks out with what I've read in documentation, which IIRC says that Pricebook and PricebookEntry cannot be edited anyway.)